# .net standard library with HttpCient for xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient, .net-standard, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

I was trying to create a common library for using `HttpClient` to consume an API. I was planning to make it in .net standard so as to share it with my xamarin.forms project right now and any future ones. However the highest version of .net standard I managed to use was 1.0. `HttpClient` needs standard2.0. I have included the latest version of .netstandard nuget into my xamarin.forms.

I have noticed that xamarin.forms runs in  net4.5. According to the documentations the max I can go with this is standard1.1. Is there any work around around these to a .net standard common project or is my only option to make a .net framework project/xamarin portable library?

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-stable-comes-to-net-standard-2-0/ Check this link - It might help you

Comment: thanks, but nop. it doesn't work. I have tried with the same version, but it doesn't allow since xamarin.forms is still in net4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to get `HttpClient` working in .net standard after manually importing the class. It needed an additional reference which is why it threw an error when I downgraded from .netcore.

This seems to work sometimes and throws reference errors other times. These errors go when I close and re-open visual studios.

Answer (score 0):

I used to be in the same situation and I managed to pull through this. First I tried to upgrade my current PCL project to .netStandard, but it was always failing, so I decided to create a new Project A **Class Library (.NETStandard)**, moved all my files to the new project and re-install all nuget packages.

New project configuration:

- Target Framwork: .NET Standard 2.0
- Output type: Class Library

Make sure you're using Microsoft Visual Studio > version 15.3

Hope it helps.

Comment: so you moved all your files from your PCL to .net standard class library?

Comment: Exactly, moved all the code file a included them in the newly created project